# How to crawl in Python while the website blocked contents not to be crawled?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a very beginner of Python and tried to crawl using BeautifulSoup. And tried to crawl a website for collecting product information.

```
pr_url = soup.findAll("li", {"class", "_3FUicfNemK"})
pr_url
```

Everything is same with the other codes of crawl using BeautifulSoup.
But the problem is nothing happened even if I wrote down right components.

So what I thought is **the host blocked the product area not to be crawled.**
Cuz every element except for the area is crawl-able.

Do you know how to crawl this blocked area?
The site url is:
https://shopping.naver.com/living/homeliving/category?menu=10004487&sort=POPULARITY

Thank you for your comments in advance!

Comment: there is no any product blocked. but, when you request to URL it takes time to load products on webpage because it might be it's come from JS. so, using BeautifulSoup, you are getting a webpage without products.

Comment: You could try using selenium and include a time delay in order to work around the issue that @ManaliKagathara has mentioned.

Comment: I might be a bit old school here, but I think that if the website doesn't want to be crawled, you shouldn't do it. That's the whole point of the `robots.txt` file, after all

Comment: Thank you for all comments! I will try it again using selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how when you first load the page the outline of the site loads but the products take a while to load up? This is because the site is requesting the rest of the content to load in the background. This content isn't blocked, it's simply loaded later :)

2 options here i.m.o...

1) Figure out the background request and pass that into beautifulsoup. Using the Chrome dev tools network tab I can see that the request for the products is...

[https://shopping.naver.com/v1/products?*nc*=1583366400000&subVertical=HOME_LIVING&page=1&pageSize=10&sort=POPULARITY&filter=ALL&displayType=CATEGORY_HOME&includeZzim=true&includeViewCount=true&includeStoreCardInfo=true&includeStockQuantity=false&includeBrandInfo=false&includeBrandLogoImage=false&includeRepresentativeReview=false&includeListCardAttribute=false&includeRanking=false&includeRankingByMenus=false&includeStoreCategoryName=false&menuId=10004487&standardSizeKeys=&standardColorKeys=&attributeValueIds=&attributeValueIdsAll=&certifications=&menuIds=&includeStoreInfoWithHighRatingReview=false](https://shopping.naver.com/v1/products?_nc_=1583366400000&subVertical=HOME_LIVING&page=1&pageSize=10&sort=POPULARITY&filter=ALL&displayType=CATEGORY_HOME&includeZzim=true&includeViewCount=true&includeStoreCardInfo=true&includeStockQuantity=false&includeBrandInfo=false&includeBrandLogoImage=false&includeRepresentativeReview=false&includeListCardAttribute=false&includeRanking=false&includeRankingByMenus=false&includeStoreCategoryName=false&menuId=10004487&standardSizeKeys=&standardColorKeys=&attributeValueIds=&attributeValueIdsAll=&certifications=&menuIds=&includeStoreInfoWithHighRatingReview=false)

Should be able to guess the tweaks to the query string here and use that.

2) Use a tool like Selenium which interacts with the browser and will execute any JavaScript for you so you don't have to figure out that side of things. If you're new to this stuff, might be less of a learning curve into web tech here.

Comment: So from the 1st para the point is that using BeautifulSoup the products will not be loaded because it is come from JS? Therefore, simply what i need to do is to use selenium. Am I understanding right? Sorry for poor english comprehension.
Anyway thank you soo much for your beautiful feedback!

Comment: "the products will not be loaded because it is come from JS" - correct :) 

Selenium might be the easiest option for you here. You can use BeautifulSoup still, try it on the url provided in the answer. Ultimately the best answer here is the one you find easiest to apply

Comment: Thank you so much. One question still left tho.
If I need to crawl loads of pages except for the url you provided, then do you still recommend to use the url? (Actually I can't get what the url exactly means, and how it works.)

Comment: You would have to backwards engineer how that link is formed on each page and then alter it based on that to scrape all of the pages. Selenium is a bit of a "higher level" tool in that you can just tell it to click link "X" and navigate the site that way and perform the scrape.

Comment: Thank you! Could you let me know which code can help me to get the form of url above in non-scroll-through websites?